# How to include external files in multi-project .vstemplate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-templates

I'm creating a VS2010 multi project template and I'm trying to make add a file (.hgignore) to the solution (not into a project) from the vstemplate.

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
< VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">

    < TemplateData>...< /TemplateData>

    < TemplateContent >

        < ProjectItem> .hgignore < /ProjectItem >

        < ProjectCollection >       

            < ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.xxx">....< /ProjectTemplateLink>
            < ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.xxx">....< /ProjectTemplateLink>

        < /ProjectCollection>

    < /TemplateContent>

< /VSTemplate>
```

Thank you very much

PS : I can't manage to make correct XML tag in the editor so I had to add white space...

Comment: Does this have something to do with Mercurial?  It's completely unobvious from your question and your tags.

Comment: No it doesn't, it has to do with how to add a file in a VS solution from a custom install template and NOT inside a project. But thanks I probably need to rewrite a bit my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do this. However, the VSTemplate wizard engine supports an extensibility model that lets you run custom logic during the solution/project creation process. You need to implement a class that implements the [IWizard interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.aspx) and then add [a WizardExtension element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171411.aspx) in your .vstemplate file.

Check out Craig Skibo's answer on [this MSDN forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d7407d60-96e3-429a-84ef-be4cb8edcf95) for the details on using the DTE automation API from your IWizard.RunFinished method to add a solution item.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this programmatically via IWizard.

Example Wizard, which copies Nuget.Config from VSIX(which is included via "Include in VSIX" property):

```
class AppCustomizationWizard : IWizard
{
    private const string NugetConfig = "Nuget.Config";

    private static string GetVsixFullPath(string filename)
    {
        var vsixDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vsixDir))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Path.Combine(
            vsixDir,
            filename
        );
    }

    private static void CopyNugetConfig(Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary)
    {
        var solutionDir = replacementsDictionary["$solutiondirectory$"];
        var vsixNugetConfig = GetVsixFullPath(NugetConfig);
        if (solutionDir != null && vsixNugetConfig != null)
        {
            File.Copy(vsixNugetConfig, Path.Combine(solutionDir, NugetConfig));
        }
    }

    public void BeforeOpeningFile(ProjectItem projectItem)
    {
    }

    public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
    {
    }

    public void ProjectItemFinishedGenerating(ProjectItem projectItem)
    {
    }

    public void RunFinished()
    {
    }

    public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary,
        WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
    {
        XElement wizardInfo = XElement.Parse(replacementsDictionary["$wizarddata$"]);
        XNamespace defaultNamespace = wizardInfo.GetDefaultNamespace();
        string itemType = wizardInfo.Element(defaultNamespace + "Type").Value;

        if (itemType == "Application")
        {
            CopyNugetConfig(replacementsDictionary);
        }
    }

    public bool ShouldAddProjectItem(string filePath)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```